# Easy way to divide $2^{1000}$ by $59$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

What will be the remainder when  $2^{1000}$ is divided by $59$? What is the easiest way to calculate this?

Comment: I'm not much for linking to Quora, but the question is exactly the same: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-remainder-when-2-1000-is-divided-by-59

Comment: Fermat's little theorem can be used here I think.

Answer (score 5):

By Fermat's Little Theorem,
$$2^{58}\equiv1\pmod{59}$$
$$(2^{58})^{17}\equiv1\pmod{59}$$
$$2^{986}\equiv1\pmod{59}$$
$$2^{1000}\equiv2^{14}\pmod{59}$$
$$2^{1000}\equiv16384\pmod{59}$$
$$2^{1000}\equiv41\pmod{59}$$

Thus, the remainder is $41$.

Comment: If you can't calculate $2^{14}$ very easily, then $2^6 \equiv 5  (\mod59)$ should help.